# How to Find User Groups through VBA

Tags: vba, shell

In MS-Dos the way to show the groups a user belongs to is by the command:

```
whoami /groups
```

I was wondering, how can one do that through VBA? How would it translate?

I thought of doing it through Shell... But the requirements I was given is not to have a dependency on Shell and find the groups a user belongs to, precisely through VBA Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below access code should give you all the groups current user belongs to :

```
Sub my_group()
    Dim myws          As DAO.Workspace
    Dim groups        As DAO.group
    Dim strGroups   As String

    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

    For Each groups In myws.Users(CurrentUser).groups
        strGroups = strGroups & "; " & groups.Name
    Next groups

    all_groups = Mid(strGroups, 3)

End Sub
```